# How to set cookies in Graphene Python mutation?

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

In [Graphene Python](http://graphene-python.org/), how should one go about setting cookies in the `schema.py` when there is no access to the `HttpResponse` object to set the cookie on?

My current implementation is to set the cookie by overriding the GraphQLView's dispatch method by catching the `data.operationName`. This involves hard-coding of the operation names / mutations that I need cookies to be set on.

In views.py:

```
class PrivateGraphQLView(GraphQLView):
    data = self.parse_body(request)
    operation_name = data.get('operationName')
    # hard-coding === not pretty.
    if operation_name in ['loginUser', 'createUser']:
        ...
        response.set_cookie(...)
    return response
```

Is there a cleaner way of setting cookies for specific Graphene Python mutations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wound up setting cookies via middleware.

```
class CookieMiddleware(object):

    def resolve(self, next, root, args, context, info):
        """
        Set cookies based on the name/type of the GraphQL operation
        """

        # set cookie here and pass to dispatch method later to set in response
        ...
```

In a custom graphql view, `views.py`, override the dispatch method to read the cookie and set it.

```
class MyCustomGraphQLView(GraphQLView):  

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(MyCustomGraphQLView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        # Set response cookies defined in middleware
        if response.status_code == 200:
            try:
                response_cookies = getattr(request, CookieMiddleware.MIDDLEWARE_COOKIES)
            except:
                pass
            else:
                for cookie in response_cookies:
                    response.set_cookie(cookie.get('key'), cookie.get('value'), **cookie.get('kwargs'))
        return response
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. I needed to be able to set the language cookie in a mutation and ended up using the request instance in combination with a custom middleware.

Here's the simplified code:

```py
class SetLanguage(Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        code = String(required=True)

    ok = Field(Boolean)
    language = Field(LanguageType)

    def mutate(root, info, code):
        info.context.set_language_cookie = code
        return SetLanguage(ok=True, language=code)
```

The mutation doesn't have access to the response so it temporarily stores the value on the request instance. Once the response has been created a custom middleware retrieves it and sets the cookie:

```py
class LanguageConfigMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)

        if code := getattr(request, "set_language_cookie", None):
            response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, code)

        return response
```

Comment: Nice example! Thank you!